# Pandas: Compare two dataframes and remove from df1 that also exists in df2

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two separate pandas dataframes (df1 and df2) and I want to remove records from df1 if the combination also exists in df2

df1

```
A     B     C     D
66    9     hi    pickle
66    5     hello ham
20    4     hi    cheese
```

df2

```
A     B     C     D
66    9     could be anything
```

Result df (remove row containing unique combination of 66 and 9 df1)

```
A     B     C     D
66    5     hello ham
20    4     hi    cheese
```

I though of using the isin method, but dont know how to use it with two columns. Is this possible without looping?

Comment: perform an outer merge on A/B with `indicator=True`, then filter

Comment: If i do this I get this result'
'''
A_x     B_x    C_x      D_x      A_y     B_y    C_y      D_y
66       9       hi         pickle  NaN   NaN  NaN    NaN
66       5       hello    ham    NaN   NaN  NaN    NaN
20       4       hi         cheeseNaN   NaN  NaN    NaN
NaN   NaN  NaN    NaN     66      9       could   be anything  
'''

Comment: `code in backticks`